# Pandas read_csv error due to pandas.io.common not importing is_url in 1.0.x

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read in a regular csv file into pandas through pd.read_csv(). I have done this on my local desktop many times before but I am using a virtual machine now and am getting this error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_url' from 'pandas.io.common' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py)
```

Can anyone help me understand what's happening and how to resolve it? I have tried updating as well as uninstalling and reinstalling pandas already.

Comment: Try on the separate script, `from pandas.io.common import is_url`, see if that's successfully imported

Comment: Please share the entire error message, a [mcve], and some information about the Python version and libraries you're using.

Comment: @smankusors - I'm getting an import error on your suggestion when using pandas 1.0.2. Rolling back to 1.0.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Always when reporting issues with pandas, **tell us `pandas.__version__`** 1.0.x is new, expect teething troubles.

Comment: When you say *"I have tried updating as well as uninstalling and reinstalling pandas"*, was that using Anaconda? Because if it was, you have to distrust conda and check it didn't roll back the version of pandas. In which case this question would be yet another `conda update` issue, and possibly not specific to pandas. But please please please **tell us the `pandas.__version__ ` already**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
conda update --force-reinstall pandas
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Got `cannot import name 'is_url' from "pandas.io.common"` error with pd.read_csv(). force reinstall fixed issue

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. it showed up after I updated all the libraries with conda (trying to fix something else). After print the version of pandas inside the notebook, it showed as a really old one (0.3.somehing, can not remember the exact number). but strangely , my other notebook files were showing pandas version as 1.0.2, and i was able to load csv in those files without ImportError . So i went back to conda and upgraded pandas again just by itself, restarted conda, ran the code again , fixed it . Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean you had multiple installs of pandas on your path, and it picked up an old one? Or that 'conda update' rolled back the pandas version?

Comment: I do not have multiple installs of pandas on my path. but somehow after update the package , it rolled back the pandas version, but not on all my notebook files. so strange.[file one shows version 1.0.2,but file 2 shows 0.3.something]

Comment: Beware of `conda update`, inspect closely which packages it rolls forward/backward. In general if you see it rolling an important package backwards, there's something wrong (e.g. with dependencies), stop and don't do the update.

Answer (score 4):

For my collab Notebooks, I restarted the kernel and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same issue. We needs to be very careful while updating conda seems its bit dangerous. I tried with above options but unfortunately it didn't worked. I just stopped my Jupyter Notebook from console and closed Anaconda Navigator then started again. It worked !!!!

Comment: Was just about to re-re-recreate the conda env when I spotted this answer and indeed, restarting the Notebook server from console fixed this ‍♂️

Comment: I am having the same issue but in my case, Jupyter Notebook runs on a Linode server and not via Anaconda. I tried solutions reported here - https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/403. Specifically, downgrading to pandas 1.1.3 from 1.1.4 pip install pandas==1.1.3. Since for most people, updating/downgrading pandas solves the issue. But this did not help. For some reason, Jupyter Notebook reports version '0.24.2' when I run in the notebook pd.__version__, but the Terminal window on the server prints pandas version as 1.1.3. ‍♂️ Will try restarting the server.

Comment: Restarting Linode (my server) sorted out the issue with different versions. Thanks, @VladIliescu